# Creating an array of JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

I was trying to create an array of JTextField and then use a loop to add each one to a JPanel.
Here is the code snippet, it doesn't seem to work.

```
public void courseCode(){
    JTextField[] courseCode = new JTextField[10];
    int y=30;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        courseCode[i].setBounds(280, y, 100, 25);
        y+=30;
        add(courseCode[i]);
    }
```

P.S: I did call the courseCode() method from the class constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of an `Object` array are `null` by default. Initialise the elements before attempting to invoke their methods

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  courseCode[i] = new JTextField();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse!, how did i let that get away from me. Thanks a lot sir.